# iOS Swift - Get BackgroundColor from selected TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ViewController with a TableView in it.
Via code, I populate the cells of the TableView and with other code, I set the Cell's BackgroundColor.
NOTE - in other parts of the code I do this with
**cell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xAA66CC)**  // although the specific RGB value for each cell will vary.

Now on my Segue to another View I want to retrieve, not only the "Name" element, but also the Cell's BackgroundColor and send it on to the next ViewController.
I am getting the "Name" just fine, but I am not sure how to get the BackgroundColor value (which I will then need to convert to a String for passing).

My Segue code is:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSeque, sender: AnyObject?)  
{  
if segue.identifier = "GoToNextVC" {  
  if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {  
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! NextVC
    let indx = tableView.IndexPathForCell(cell).row
    destination.SelectedValue = self.peripherals[indx].name // This works fine.  

    destination.SelectedColor = **< I don't know what to do here >**
    }  
  }  
}
```

That code works to get the SelectedObject Name, but I am not sure how to get the Cell's BackgroundColor so that I can then pass it through the Segue.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not that I've tried it, but is there something wrong with the obvious: `cell.backgroundColor`?

Comment: try cell.contentView.backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

I will try with:

```
cell.backgroundColor
```

If you have cell then you can get the color.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSeque, sender: AnyObject?)  
{  
  if segue.identifier = "GoToNextVC" {  
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {  
      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! NextVC
      let indx = tableView.IndexPathForCell(cell).row
      destination.SelectedValue = self.peripherals[indx].name // This works fine.  

      destination.SelectedColor = cell.backgroundColor
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  What I have found:  1)  **cell.backgroundColor!**   gives the UIColor   2)  AND  **cell.contentView.backgroundColor!**   also gives me the UIColor  -- I am not sure what the difference is, but it is a start.

Comment: I have a routine to get the UIColor into RGBA, but now I need to get the RGBA values consolidated into a single HEX String.   Any suggestions?